# Add specific javascript code to a wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have found [some code](http://jsfiddle.net/C6LPY/2/) I want to use to a single page in my wordpress site, but I cannot find the way to do it. I am not a developer, but a newbie.

I have html and css ready, but I don't know **how to run this javascript code** to a page with **id 2922**, every time the page loads.

```
$(function () {
var parent = $("#shuffle");
var divs = parent.children();
while (divs.length) {
    parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
}
});
```

Thanks for your help,
Thodoris

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: I can't make it work. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this code in footer.php[site/wp-content/your-theme/footer.php]

```
<?php if(get_the_ID()== 2922){ ?>
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function () {
            var parent = jQuery("#shuffle");
            var divs = parent.children();
            while (divs.length) {
                parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

or read this https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/how-to-add-javascript-in-a-wordpress-post-or-page-1845

Comment: The script is working! Thanks @Ram! I've used different "if", because yours isn't working. The final code: `<?php if ( is_page( 3318 ) ) : ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function () {
            var parent = jQuery("#shuffle");
            var divs = parent.children();
            while (divs.length) {
                parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>` (ID is different because I created a new page).

Comment: Script wasn't working below `<head>`, but it worked above `</head>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from jQuery. In your script add condition to check if body has class of that page id is same as your `page-id-2922`, if yes then run the code.

I have updated your script, try using it:

```
$(function () {

    if( $('body').hasClass('page-id-2922') == true ){
        var parent = $("#shuffle");
        var divs = parent.children();
        while (divs.length) {
            parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Where exactly to put this code? How to do this from jQuery, as you said?

Comment: @ThodorisKonsoulas - just use this in your any custom js file you write. & it will work,  It doesnt need php code & It is the standard practice to write code instead using multiple language for a single functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it into the `single.php` with a conditional like so:

```
<?php if ( is_page(3318) ) : ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            var parent = $("#shuffle");
            var divs = parent.children();
            while (divs.length) {
                parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It will add the escript on the page only if it is the single post with ID 3318.

EDIT: added right answer and changed to the correct ID.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tested your script but nothing happened. Here is the page: http://www.fomo.gr/test-page-2/. There is no random order for images.

Comment: Are you sure the ID is 2911? Did you check if the _script_ gets outputted into the page? Your page looks to have a different ID, so it won't add the `script`

Comment: I put the correct ID (3318), but still nothing. My page uses the theme's "template-fullwidth.php". Maybe try there the above code?

Comment: Yes. Or as others suggested put it in the footer or header files, those files load for every page/post.

Comment: Nothing again. No random order. :( Maybe the "is_single(3318)" isn't working?

Comment: It should. Try with out the ID, just `is_single()` or even with out it.

Comment: [`ìs_single` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/)

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working. I have the code as you said before </header>. Div's in page seem fine to me.

Comment: Yup it should. I meant _header.php_ file inside the `<head>` tag. Or in the _footer.php_ file inside the `<footer>` tag.
Try first with out the `if` statment. If it works test the `if ( is_single() )`, we might have a problem there.

Comment: I put the code`<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(function () {
            var parent = $("#shuffle");
            var divs = parent.children();
            while (divs.length) {
                parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
            }
        });
    </script>` below <head> and now Firefox Console says "ReferenceError: $ is not defined".

Comment: That should work, but load the code for everypage. I can't see what is wrong :(

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Just to know Christian, this worked: `<?php if ( is_page( 3318 ) ) : ?> <script type='text/javascript'> jQuery(function () { var parent = jQuery("#shuffle"); var divs = parent.children(); while (divs.length) { parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]); } }); </script> <?php endif; ?>` :)

Comment: Ohhh, it should have worked the whole time, I missed the point that you were on a page, not on a post. So yes the function is `is_page` and not `is_single`. Sorry. But the good thing is you got it working :)